# Записываются лишние символы в файл

Tags: java, android

```
 public void writeLine(String path, String text)
{
    File f = new File(path);
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        osw.write(text);
        osw.close();
        fos.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "writeLine: length" + text.length());
        Log.d(TAG, "writeLine: length" + f.length());
        Log.d(TAG, "writeLine: string json " + text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

строка длинной 75 а длинна файла 95. При чтении записываются лишние символы (в консоли ромбы с вопросом)

> Cтрока прочитана:
>   {"dictionary":{"машина":"car","молоко":"milk","собака":"dog","мама":"mam","хлеб":"bread"}}����������������������������������������������������

```
 public char[] readLine(String path)
    {
        File f = new File(path);
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            Log.d("lab2","Файл открыт: " + path);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("lab2","Файл НЕ открыт: " + path);
        }
        try{
            if(br!=null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "readLine: file length " + f.length());
                char arr[] = new char[(int)f.length()];
                br.read(arr);
                Log.d("lab2","Cтрока прочитана: " + new String(arr));
                Log.d("lab2","Length: " + arr.length);
                br.close();
                return arr;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("lab2","Cтрока НЕ прочитана: " + path);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример. как это сделать описано тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: я проверял с обычной строкой (hello world), все работает, но когда я вставляю json появляется такая проблема.

Comment: обычно когда пытаются создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример, то очень быстро обнаруживают проблему. попробуйте - может у вас тоже получиться.

Comment: `f.length()` возвращает размер файла в байтах, а вы создаете символьный массив. Поскольку файл, скорее всего, в utf8, то букв в нем меньше (русские занимают 2 байта), и вы получаете строку с нулевыми символами в конце.

Comment: @SanychGoilo Вам нужно прочитать одну строку или весь файл?

Comment: @Evgeniy файл..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать следующий метод для чтения:

```
public char[] readLine(String path)
{
    File f = new File(path);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        Log.d("lab2","Файл открыт: " + path);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("lab2","Файл НЕ открыт: " + path);
    }
    try{
        if(br!=null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "readLine: file length " + f.length());

            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("lab2","Cтрока прочитана: " + line);
                Log.d("lab2","Length: " + line.length());
                text.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            return text.toString().toCharArray();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("lab2","Cтрока НЕ прочитана: " + path);
    }
    return null;
}
```